# Flattening nested dictionaries with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, nested

So I have a dictionary of the form `Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, Object>> myObjects` and I would like to flatten this to a `List<Object> flattenedObjects` as simply as possible. I tried to come up with a clever solution, but so far all I've gotten to work is a solution with two nested foreach -loops that iterate over all of the elements, but I suppose there should be a nicer way of accomplishing this with LINQ.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

try this

```
List<Object> flattenedObjects = myObjects.Values.SelectMany(myObject => myObject.Values).ToList();
```

Answer (score 8):

Like this:

```
var result = myObjects.Values.SelectMany(d => d.Values).ToList();
```